# Puppeteer fails to parse deep objects in DOM

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I've been trying out Puppeteer to scrap profile pictures from Instagram. The goal is: with an instagram username, go to https://instagram.com/username, find profile picture URL in DOM and get the `src` attribute of the profile picture.

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto('https://instagram.com/tyva.tlse');
const arrayOfImgElements = await page.$$("img");
console.log(arrayOfImgElements);
```

I expected this code to return a table with all `<img>` elements on the page. However it shows only 2 elements of the Instagram page: the Instagram and Meta logo. It seems that the "deepest" elements in the page's DOM are not found.

It seems to work with a 5 second delay. Seems that the deep data needs more time to load.

Would you have a solution or workaround to parse these images that are ignored?